# Showing percentage in the Grafana graph histogram

Tags: histogram, grafana

I have a use case in grafana. I have a speed vs Time graph. I would like to show a histogram in grafana with 15 buckets each. The 'Y' axis instead of showing the count, should show the percentage of the total count.

How is this possible?

Comment: Is this for the Grafana Graph panel displaying as bars, or is it a different plugin? Also, what version of Grafana are you using?

Comment: My grafana version is 6.2.1, I am using the graph panel. Histogram panel is not working. I am open to any other alternative

Answer (score 1):

In the graph panel go into the metrics pane and do the following:

1. Set the draw mode to bar
2. Under Axes/Left Y select Units
3. From the Units drop-down select Misc > percent (0-100)

This will display the left Y axis in percent.

Comment: It just convert the total counts to percent, which is wrong. I would like it to be count/total * 100

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you are using but lets assume you are using Prometheus and your promql is similar to below:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id!="/",namespace=~"$Namespace",pod_name=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m])) by (pod_name)
```

This gives you the cpu usage of pods in milliunite which is 1/1000 of a cpu capacity. For changing it to percent I just need to multiply it by 100 and for that I will add `* 100` to the end of query.

Now the solution to your answer: if `q` is your current query then you can get the percent by changing the query like this: ((q)/total) * 100

At the end as @Phil said change the units to percent.

Comment: I am using influx

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference I just mentioned prometheus as an example. If you go to the edit then the first thing you see is the queries section and then you can do as I said, just put all your current query into parentheses as I described.